# Why use ImageIcon rather than Image?

Tags: java, image, object, imageicon

In what instance would I want to use ImageIcon to represent a picture file rather than an Image object? I've been searching and I've seen people say that you would use an ImageIcon object when dealing with images that will be part of the GUI, but I still don't understand the implications of this. In other words, what is the actual difference between the two object types and what situations are they each suited for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Image` is an object that represents a bitmap: an array of pixels of different colors.

`Icon` is an object that can draw a rectangular piece of graphics. Since it is an interface (and a simple one too), you can imagine many different types of icons: drawing predefined vector graphics, generating images on the fly etc. Therefore it is a useful abstraction and is used by Swing components (buttons, labels).

`ImageIcon` is an object that IS an `Icon`, but HAS-A `Image`. That is - it draws graphics based on a specific image.

When you say "why should I be using an ImageIcon instead of Image" you miss the point: in fact you are using an `Image` either way.

Answer (score 2):

An `Image` is an object representing the data model of a picture. An `ImageIcon` is a Swing component that draws an `Image` on the screen, and you have to provide it with the appropriate `Image` to draw (either by passing in an existing `Image` or by giving it enough information to find and load the image).

The relationship is similar to that between a `String` and a `JTextField`; one is the representation of the data, and the other is the graphical component that draws it on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation is to not hold up the Swing thread.

> Images that are created from a URL, filename or byte array are preloaded using MediaTracker to monitor the loaded state of the image.

Basically, then you can set an ImageIcon for a button without actually forcing it to be loaded beforehand.

This can be seen by having a very large icon and setting the Frame's icon to this image. Once set visible, it may take a few seconds to actually appear.